# different words to explain the fragrance of flowers

Tags: word-request, synonyms

"The garden is fragrant with jasmine flowers"
Is there a different way to say this? I would appreciate an alternate word for "fragrant"

Comment: google **fragrant synonyms**

Comment: I did. There are different words like scent, aroma and others. However, I am unable to fit them as a replacement in the above quoted sentence

Comment: If it helps, think of how the scent affects you, then use words like that. For example, if you disliked jasmine, you could say, "That nasty and tiny garden reeked of jasmine." If you thought jasmine was sensual, you could say, "Jasmine perfumed the air like the kiss from a secret love by moonlight." You get the idea.

Comment: _Scent_ is a synonym of _fragrance_, not _fragrant_!

Comment: As @KateBunting says, "scent" and "aroma" are nouns, and that is probably why you can't "fit them as a replacement". Look in a thesaurus for adjectives. One that might work is "redolent". ("The garden is redolent with the smell of jasmine flowers.")

Answer (score 1):

The garden **is filled with the scent or aroma or fragrance of jasmine**.

That is a more idiomatic way of saying this.